# PHP Access nested object property via strings in array

Tags: php, oop, properties

Let's say we have an object $obj. This object has a property which is as follows:

```
$obj->p1->p2->p3 = 'foo';
```

Now I get the nested property structure in an array:

```
$arr = array( 'p1', 'p2', 'p3' );
```

Currently I use the following function to access the property accordingly:

```
function getProperty( $obj, $property ) {
foreach( $property as $p ) {
  $obj = $obj->{$p};
 }
 return $obj;
}

$value = getProperty( $obj, $arr); // = 'foo'
```

Is there a smarter way to do that (no, 'eval' is not an option! ;) )?

Comment: If it works why would you want to improve it.

Comment: There's no urgent need to change it. But it seems to be a little bit complicated and not very elegant.

Comment: In addition, this is part of a very complex script and execution time is a relevant point here...

Comment: I don't think you can make it "prettier". Here is an alternative to foreach with array_reduce. function getProperty($object, array $keys) { return array_reduce($keys, function($carry, $item) { return $carry->{$item}; }, $object); }

Comment: Thank you! The more I think about it, the more I think there's really no "prettier" way. ;)

Comment: So am I understanding this correctly, `p1` and `p2` are both objects and `p3` is a property for a value `string`. How complicated a script becomes depends on its design and its true, the reason your questioning here, to find better solutions or more appropriate designs. By the looks if it, this is horrible. How are `p1` and `p2` being instantiated and what is the relevance/relations between `p2` and `p1`, also `p1` and `$obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it in one line or a bit prettier, you can try this:

```
echo json_decode(json_encode($obj), true)['p1']['p2']['p3']; // PHP 5.4
```

or for PHP 5.3:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
echo $arr['p1']['p2']['p3'];
```

Is that the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: Now that looks nice. ;) But the object can be very big with many properties. Have to check the execution time of encoding to and decoding from json.